# Good pattern for multiphase algorithm?

Tags: c#, algorithm, coding-style, refactoring

Is there a pattern (refactoring) to improve this piece of code?

```
    int phase = 0;
    foreach (var some in arrayOfSome)
    {
        if (phase == 0)
        {
            bool result = DoSomething_0(some);
            if (result) phase = 1;
        }
        else if (phase == 1)
        {
            bool result = DoSomething_1(some);
            if (result) phase = 0;

            result = DoSomething_1_0(some);
            if (result) phase = 2;
        }
        else if (phase == 2)
        {
            bool result = DoSomething_2(some);
            if (result) break;
        }
    }
```

First of all, I want to reduce the number of conditional operators and make the code more readable.

Comment: A minor improvement would be using enums instead of ints for your state/phase as you can provide them proper labels indicating what the current phase is supposed to mean instead of non-descript numbers.

Comment: Looks like a good case for applying the State pattern

Comment: Usually `phase` would be called `state`, since what you've written is a state machine, and usually you would use `switch`/`case` instead of a bunch of `if`s, but otherwise it seems fine.  You can also use `phase==-1` or something to indicate the exit condition and test it at the top of the loop.

Comment: The code is confusing and it's not clear to me that it is correct. Suppose we are on the first item in arrayOfSome, phase is zero, the result of DoSomething_0 is true, the result of DoSomething_1 is false, the result of DoSomething_1_0 is true, and the result of DoSomething_2 is false. We then start the loop on the *second* item in arrayOfSome, but phase is still set to 2. Is that correct? Get the code *correct* before you try to figure out how to refactor it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An elegant approach is to eliminate the if/then logic altogether. You can do this by creating an array of delegates indexed by state (phase). Each delegate slot in the array points at a function (or lambda) that does whatever and returns the new state (phase).

In these kinds of designs, you often end up with a loop that contains a single statement like this:

```
foreach (var x in data)
{
    state = handler[state](x);
}
```

I've coded this kind of FSM many times and they are very generic when done correctly and very reliable. Bugs almost always boil down to small errors in handlers or incorrect handlers being defined for a given state/input combination.

A more general and powerful design has this pattern:

```
foreach (var x in data)
{
    state = handler[state,x](x);
}
```

Where both the state and datum are used to select the handler delegate. There are huge benefits when using this pattern in that the temptation to add extra flags and conditions within the loop as the code or functionality grows over time.

The code you posted is OK but if - after time - one ends up with ten different states and umpteen conditions and many handlers then very subtle hard to fix bugs will creep in that are almost impossible sometimes to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Don't see the need for refactoring here. Maybe you could reduce some lines and write it like this:

```
int phase = 0;
foreach (var some in arrayOfSome)
{
    if (phase == 0)
    {
        if (DoSomething_0(some)) phase = 1;
    }
    if (phase == 1)
    {
        if (DoSomething_1(some)) phase = 0;
        if (DoSomething_1_0(some)) phase = 2;
    }
    if (phase == 2)
    {
        if (DoSomething_2(some)) break;
    }
}
```

If you are concerned with too many if's within a for (again it is readable in your case) you can have a look at [Flattening Arrow Code](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/)

Comment: The problem is that at each iteration, the current phase is checked, although the phase (and, accordingly, the processing logic) is known prior to iteration.

Comment: I think that a good solution is to determine the logic of processing at the time of choosing the next phase. But I don't know how to implement it.

Comment: Unless you are writing some performance critical code in C or assembly, you really don't need to worry about conditional statements performance. It really is no performance issue for C#.